# How to use Mathematica functions in Python programs?

Tags: programming, mathlink-or-wstp, interoperability, python

I'd like to know how can I call Mathematica functions from Python.

I appreciate a example, for example, using the Mathematica function **[Prime](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Prime.html)**.

I had search about [MathLink](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/MathLinkAndExternalProgramCommunicationOverview.html) but how to use it in Python is a little obscure to me.

I tried to use a Mathematica-Python library called *[pyml](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/585/)* but I hadn't no sucess, maybe because this lib looks very old (in tutorial says Mathematica 2 or 3).

So, someone knows a good way to write python programs who uses Mathematica functions and can give me an example?

**Old Edit:**

*Maybe this edit can help someone who wants to use mathlinks directly.*

*To another solution, please see the answer accepted.*

Using the *Wolfram/Mathematica/8.0/SystemFiles/Links/Python* I could had sucess in compiling the module changing some things in setup.py.

*My architechture is `x86-64`.*

1-Change the `mathematicaversion` to `8.0`.

2-Changing the lib name `ML32i3` to `ML64i3`.

3-Copying the file `Wolfram/Mathematica/8.0/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/libML64i3.so` to the path pointed in setup.py `library_dirs = ["/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/" + mathematicaversion + "/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux/CompilerAdditions"]`.

5-Compiling the source with `sudo python setup.py build`.

6-Installing the lib with `sudo python setup.py install`

4-Editing the file `/etc/ld.so.conf` and putting the line 
`include /usr/local/lib`.

5-Creating a directory in `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mathlink` 
with the lib `libML64i3.so`.

6-Running `sudo ldconfig`

I had tested the scripts `guifrontend.py` with `python guifrontend.py -linkname "math -mathlink" -linkmode launch` and `textfrontend.py` with `python textfrontend.py -linkname "math -mathlink" -linkmode launch` and worked fine.

Looks like I almost. But the script

```
>>> from mathlink import *
>>> import exceptions,sys, re, os
>>> from types import ListType
>>> mathematicaversion = "8.0"
>>> os.environ["PATH"] = "/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/" + mathematicaversion + ":/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
>>> e = env()
>>> sys.argv=['textfrontend.py', '-linkname', 'math -mathlink', '-linkmode', 'launch']
>>> kernel = e.openargv(sys.argv)
>>> kernel.connect()
>>> kernel.ready()
0
>>> kernel.putfunction("Prime",1)
>>> kernel.putinteger(10)
>>> kernel.flush()
>>> kernel.ready()
0
>>> kernel.nextpacket()
8
>>> packetdescriptiondictionary[3]
'ReturnPacket'
>>> kernel.getinteger()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
mathlink.error: MLGet out of sequence.
```

breaks in the last command and I don't know why. How can I fix this?

Comment: Mathematica comes with Python bindings.  They are found in `SystemFiles/Links/Python` in the Mathematica installation directory.  You need to compile the C language part yourself before you can use this.  This link is unsupported an the readme file says: "WRI has made no attempt to make the mathlink module compliant
with versions of Python newer than 2.3.".  I never used it so I can't tell you if it works with newer Pythons, but I'd give it a try.

Comment: @Szabolcs. I tried to build the module to use this link. Unfortunally no sucess. Several error ocurrs when trying to run `python setup.py build`.

Comment: Well, what errors did you get and what have you tried to do to fix them?  Have you read the documentation on how to compile?

Comment: In documentations says the first thing is run this command (above) to create the module. The erros are so large that flooded my shell. See a part of it [here](http://pastebin.com/5Va8zJPY). I think solve all of this is out of my hands.

Comment: Changing the `mathematicaversion` in setup.py we have few erros. But, still erros, no found. [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/dvtTnTYx).

Comment: Looks like you're trying to link against the 32-bit version of MathLink while compiling for 64 bit.  Try changing ML32i3 to ML64i3.

Comment: not found =/. `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lML64i3`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3199/discussion-between-szabolcs-and-garoudan)

Comment: Are there specific Mathematica *only* functions that you need to call? If not, it's quite likely that another library implements what you're after. `numpy` is an extensive math library for `Python`, for example.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783564/possible-to-use-mathematica-from-other-programming-languages-python-c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466217/create-a-graph-using-mathematica-and-python

Comment: Is an interesting point, but, I would like the power that I know is available in Mathematica and use it. So, numpy and scypy looks a litle behind in this power to me.

Comment: I had found a solution and I posted it as a answer and I will embrace it soon. Thx a lot for help everybody.

Comment: Thx a lot @Szabolcs.

Comment: Thx Peter about your clue.

Comment: I had found a solution and I posted it as an answer. I'll embrace it soon.

Comment: Well I didn't help much.  And while I compiled it on Windows, and I can load the library, I didn't yet manage to get it to launch and link to a kernel successfully...

Comment: This was cross posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276834/how-to-use-mathematica-functions-in-python-programs).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This solution can work with several programming languages. Check this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/GarouDan/Mathematica) of mine.

See this [link](http://sapiensgarou.blogspot.com.br/2012/06/how-to-run-mathematica-functions-on.html).

I have found a solution. Works fine to me.

**Steps:**

1-Create a script named **runMath** with the content:

```
#!/usr/bin/env wolframscript
# for certain older versions of Mathematica replace 'wolframscript' by
# 'MathematicaScript -script' in the shebang line

value=ToExpression[$ScriptCommandLine[[2]]];

(*The next line prints the script name.*)
(*Print[$ScriptCommandLine[[1]]];*)

Print[value];
```

2-I gave execution privilege to the file.

```
sudo chmod +x runMath
```

3-Moved the file to the execution path

```
sudo mv runMath /usr/local/bin/
```

4-Created a new script called **run** with the content:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from subprocess import *
from sys import *

command='/usr/local/bin/runMath'
parameter=argv[1]

call([command,parameter])
```

5-Moved to the execution path

```
sudo mv run /usr/local/bin
```

6-Finally, tested it:

```
$run Prime[100]
541

$run 'Sum[2x-1,{x,1,k}]'
k^2

$run Integrate[Log[x],x]
-x + x*Log[x]

$run 'Zeta[2]'
Pi^2/6
```

You can use with ou without `'`. The `'` are needed to command with spaces.

```
$run 'f[n_] := f[n] = f[n - 1] + f[n - 2]; f[1] = f[2] = 1; Table[f[n],{n,5}]'
{1, 1, 2, 3, 5}
```

Happy!

Comment: Is there a solution for Mac since it does not allow any changes in /usr/bin (since EI Capitan)

Answer (score 11):

You can call Mathematica function in Python using the Python MathLink module (the source you found in .../SystemFiles/Links/Python), though you'll need to edit a couple of setup files to get it up and running (support@wolfram.com should be able to help you out there).

To use Prime from Python you would run something like:

> > > kernel.ready()
> >
> > 0
> >
> > > kernel.putfunction("Prime",1)
> > >
> > > kernel.putinteger(10)
> > >
> > > kernel.flush()
> > >
> > > kernel.ready()
> >
> > 1
> >
> > > kernel.nextpacket()
> >
> > 3
> >
> > > packetdescriptiondictionary[3]
> >
> > 'ReturnPacket'
> >
> > > kernel.getinteger()
> >
> > 29

Comment: Looks like I'm almost `nikko`^^. Almost everything runned but the final command breaks. Could you take a look in this [pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/BydJZF01) and tell to me what's going on?

Comment: Thx a lot about your help nikko.

Comment: what is the source code license for Python MathLink C API?

Answer (score 10):

Better late than never, but the error in the python script appears to be due to the format of the current packet.  Using your routine (with k = kernel):

```
>>> k.putfunction("Prime",1)
>>> k.putinteger(10)
>>> k.flush()
>>> k.nextpacket()
8
```

8 is a RETURNPKT, but what is the kernel returning?

```
>>> k.getnext()
34
>>> tokendictionary[34]
'MLTKSTR'
```

The kernel wants to send you a string, let's grab that instead

```
>>> k.getstring()
'In[1]:= '
```

I have noticed this behavior with the Python MathLink, namely that the kernel pretty adamantly wants to send us the first input prompt.  Fair enough.  Continuing:

```
>>> k. nextpacket()
3
>>> tokendictionary[k.getnext()]
'MLTKINT'
>>> k.getinteger()
29
```

Finally.  The lesson here is that the python MathLink bindings need the end-user to pay very close attention to the packets being sent and their type.  It is also very unforgiving; once you have thrown an error, no other kernel requests will be honored until k.clearerror() is called.

Answer (score 8):

Try Jupyter and SAGE notebook extensions for Mathematica:

http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/interfaces/sage/interfaces/mathematica.html

https://github.com/bjedwards/IPython-mathematicamagic-extension

Answer (score 7):

As yet another solution, you can use a new package called [PJLink](https://github.com/b3m2a1/PJLink) which implements JLink for python.

Once you have the package installed you start a `KernelLink` object and can use that to either evaluate strings or use the `MathematicaBlock` helper to write Mathematica-esque code:

```python
>>> import sys, os
>>> path_to_PJLink = os.path.expanduser("~/Documents/Python/IDEA/PJLink")
>>> sys.path.insert(0, path_to_PJLink)
>>> from PJLink import create_kernel_link
>>> kernel = create_kernel_link()
>>> kernel.evaluateString("$Version")
'11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)'
>>> with MathematicaBlock():
...   print(kernel.evaluate(RandomReal([-1, 1], [5, 5, 5])))
... 
[[[ 0.82333428 -0.22120173  0.28668275  0.04229312  0.92312944]
  [-0.43474731  0.64218193 -0.54186876 -0.6428228  -0.21671452]
  [-0.05066144 -0.29888543 -0.45723433  0.46926194 -0.72166916]
  [ 0.60358171  0.67254163  0.22736352  0.42711063  0.702733  ]
  [ 0.89118955 -0.76092357  0.65784946  0.42381519 -0.18184603]]

 [[-0.05566714  0.32324674  0.16537235  0.29394423 -0.3826456 ]
  [-0.30799836  0.61072882  0.87721626 -0.40292037 -0.99221593]
  [ 0.79848099  0.86318783 -0.09653227 -0.30479808  0.81070852]
  [ 0.15083946  0.71684487 -0.54012157 -0.70812674  0.16847963]
  [-0.54408339 -0.17084765  0.25754549  0.62201424 -0.41126613]]

 [[ 0.24181817  0.65082232 -0.9448459  -0.6740693  -0.70014564]
  [ 0.04181131 -0.45243563  0.02266605  0.67429721  0.53853541]
  [ 0.79842224  0.38250834 -0.42321046  0.62054957 -0.78189105]
  [ 0.91608362  0.91750963 -0.03043691  0.35382865 -0.42971801]
  [ 0.05856562  0.38297739  0.21494046 -0.77326953 -0.06090548]]

 [[-0.38581506  0.40810805 -0.06970923  0.58814432  0.970209  ]
  [-0.63803971 -0.26755306 -0.55287498  0.51696225  0.2504991 ]
  [ 0.57078906 -0.40804371 -0.26543291 -0.05022896 -0.34215896]
  [-0.27644055 -0.06931716  0.17401444 -0.5905933  -0.74513478]
  [ 0.16364204 -0.12781597 -0.77921589  0.90835378 -0.86846471]]

 [[-0.00391625  0.64797141 -0.32733043 -0.85628204 -0.39096691]
  [ 0.99579966 -0.08433519 -0.94709096  0.42123235 -0.35505469]
  [ 0.62157133  0.85142865  0.63162374 -0.43469092 -0.86983996]
  [ 0.98171147  0.0102183  -0.45457086 -0.40369601  0.45952086]
  [ 0.38977525 -0.23563561 -0.66688691  0.51853403  0.23597912]]]
```

that last bit there returned as a `numpy.ndarray` since I had NumPy installed, but it uses a different `memoryview`-esque thing if there's no NumPy to use

Answer (score 6):

I haven't done this before, so can't share any useful experiences, but you can try using `JLink` from [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) to connect to Mathematica. I am fairly sure that the amount of glue code necessary will be quite small.

A quick hack to make your attempt for PyhtonLink work would be to add the folder with the mentioned shared lib to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (Linux). You can do so by modifying some global scripts, or you can start your process in a shell script, having first redefined `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` there.

Comment: Leonid, thx about your clue. Firstly I will try just with python as I'm trying above. But if I do not have any success I will try Jython^^. Anyway, if you can take the time to look at this and get a running code I would like to know. Thx.

Comment: @GarouDan I will keep this in mind, and try it when I get some time on my hands, but this won't probably be until the end of the week.

Comment: Leonid, I had found a solution. Take a look after. Thx about your help.

Answer (score 1):

In May 16, 2019, [Wolfram Client Library for Python](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/WolframClientForPython/) is announced, so nowadays the problem can be solved easily with:

```python
from wolframclient.evaluation import WolframLanguageSession
from wolframclient.language import wl

session = WolframLanguageSession()

session.evaluate(wl.Prime(50))
#229
```