# How to batch run Mathematica code from Python?

Tags: parallelization, scripting, python

I have this notebook:

```
arg1 = "input.txt";
arg2 = "output.txt";
u1 = Import[arg1, "Table"];
u2 = u1(*extremely complicated and long chain of operations*);
Export[arg2, u2]
```

and I would like to run it in a Python program like this:

```
def run(arg1,arg2):
    my_mathematica_code(arg1,arg2)

for i in range(100):
    run("input{}".format(i), "output{}".format(i))
```

How can I do this? Preferably without GUI and several threads in parallel (I can use 4 cores in Mathematica).

Comment: related - if you don't mind putting things into a function: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4643/how-to-use-mathematica-functions-in-python-programs

Comment: Does this also works for code in my notebook which lies at some arbitrary location on my machine?

Comment: Why not open a connection to a kernel with `subprocess.Popen`? Then you can communicate with that via pipes.