# calling mathematica code in Python

Tags: interoperability

I am wondering if there is any working example of calling mathematica 9 outputs in python?

or plotting mathematica output in python?

Comment: take a look here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4643/how-to-use-mathematica-functions-in-python-programs