# Importing Mathematica defined function in python to do further computations. [Mathematica-Python interfacing]

Tags: python, external-calls

Say I have a function **FUN** defined in *Mathemtica* notebook:

```
FUN[{s1_, s2_, s3_, p_}] := 
 Block[{S, V, eigS, eigV, dev1, dev2, dev3, dev4, fun},
  S = {{s1, s2*Cos[p]}, {s2*Sin[p], s3}};
  V = {{s2, s1*Sin[p]}, {s1*Cos[p], s3}};
  eigS = Sqrt@Eigenvalues[S.ConjugateTranspose[S]];
  eigV = Sqrt@Eigenvalues[V.ConjugateTranspose[V]];
  dev1 = (eigS[[1]] - 1.2)/0.1; dev2 = (eigS[[2]] - 2.2)/0.15;
  dev3 = (eigV[[1]] - 0.3)/0.08; dev4 = (eigV[[2]] - 1.9)/0.2;
  fun = dev1^2 + dev2^2 + dev3^2 + dev4^2;
  Return[fun];]
```

Now, I want to minimize this function **FUN** using *python* optimizer (*scipy* in particular).
Question is, how within *python IDLE*, I import this *Mathematica* function **FUN**, and feed it to *scipy* optimizer to minimize it? I am familiar with how to minimize a function defined in *python* to be minimized using *scipy.optimize* solvers.

Please note that the example I am giving here is a trivial function and can be easily minimized within *Mathemtica* itself. But for practical purpose, I am interested in very complicated function (and I am interested in minimizing using *scipy* solvers). For several practical reasons, the functions I am interested in are coded within *Mathemtica* (meaning, rewriting these functions in *python* is not the option I am interested in).

I appreciate your valuable comments. Thank you in advance.

Comment: "For several practical reasons" you prefer not to rewrite these functions in python. Hmm...  But you have to consider that mixed approaches require more work in the long run. The function that you provide as an illustration is as easy to implement in python. And reverse is also true, one can do optimization and root finding in MA as well.

Comment: Hi yarchik, yes. I did not want to specify why I want the function to be defined in Mathematica. The reason is, the functions that I am defining are very complicated and use a few external packages, all written in Mathematica language. So I call several pre-defined functions from several external Mathematica packages.

Comment: Hi yarchik, the reply to your second part of the query is: yes, I only want to minimize in python. The reason is, my actual functions are so complicated that within Mathemtica, using built-in functions, such as NMinimize / FindRoot fail badly. This is not a new experience for me. This is why I typically run all minimization in python. Unfortunately, now I have a function that must be coded in Mathematica (reason as stated in my last reply).

Comment: Could you use Mathematica `C` code generator and build a wrapper with python, then optimize the wrapper which calls the C code?

Comment: Hi Beny, I haven't used `CCodeGenerator` before. My understanding is, it will convert the existing code to be used. From Wolfram page I see their examples with simple functions. I cannot say whether this can be done for my original function, which is in fact not just a single function (as mentioned above, it calls several more function from several other external Mathematica packages). But I will explore the possibility, as you mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Wolfram Client For Python](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/WolframClientForPython/index.html) allows Mathematica code to be called from Python. Following the strategy explained [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/218729/how-to-run-a-mathematica-package-m-from-python-using-the-wolfram-client-libr?rq=1) start by creating a Mathematica Package (.m file) with the function of interest:

```
BeginPackage["targetFunctions`"]
FUN::usage = "FUN[{s1,s2,s3,p}]";
Begin["Private`"]
FUN[{s1_, s2_, s3_, p_}] := 
 Block[{S, V, eigS, eigV, dev1, dev2, dev3, dev4, fun}, 
  S = {{s1, s2*Cos[p]}, {s2*Sin[p], s3}};
  V = {{s2, s1*Sin[p]}, {s1*Cos[p], s3}};
  eigS = Sqrt@Eigenvalues[S.ConjugateTranspose[S]];
  eigV = Sqrt@Eigenvalues[V.ConjugateTranspose[V]];
  dev1 = (eigS[[1]] - 1.2)/0.1; dev2 = (eigS[[2]] - 2.2)/0.15;
  dev3 = (eigV[[1]] - 0.3)/0.08; dev4 = (eigV[[2]] - 1.9)/0.2;
  fun = dev1^2 + dev2^2 + dev3^2 + dev4^2;
  Return[fun]]
End[]
EndPackage[]
```

You can then define a target function in Python in the following way

```python
from wolframclient.evaluation import WolframLanguageSession
from wolframclient.language import wl
    
wolfSession = WolframLanguageSession()
wolfSession.evaluate(wl.Needs("targetFunctions`"))
    
def target(x):
    return wolfSession.evaluate(wl.targetFunctions.FUN((x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3])))
```

scipy.optimize may be employed in a straightforward way, for example:

```python
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np
x0 = np.array([0,0,0,0])
res = minimize(target, x0)
print(res.x)
```

Finally, terminate the Wolfram session

```python
wolfSession.terminate()
```

Comment: Thank you! This is very nice. Though I am a little confused. For this particular example, Mathematica finds much better minimum than Python, which is highly surprising. Do you have any idea why this strange behavior?

Comment: @string, I didn't examine the target function. In which sense is a minimum computed within Mathematica better than one calculated with the Mathematica-Python strategy presented above?