# How to make a package of notations using the notation package

Tags: packages, custom-notation, notation

Alternative question: how to postfixify prefix operators like @, /@, @@

I would like to make a package of notations using the notation package. I want to make postfix notations for common prefix operators.

Edit:

Before addressing the main problem, I will consider a simpler problem that looks like it could work but it does not.

```
BeginPackage["notations`",{"Notation`"}]

jj::usage="unusual choice for a postfix version of @ "

Begin["`Private`"]

Notation`AutoLoadNotationPalette = False;

Notation[NotationTemplateTag[o_ jj y_  ] \ 
[DoubleLongRightArrow] NotationTemplateTag[y_@o_]]

End[]

EndPackage[]
```

The error displayed when loading the package in a notebook:

*"The external representation NotationTemplateTag[jj\ o_\ y_] does not 

have an embedded TemplateBox with tag NotationTemplateTag. The 

Notation statement Notation[NotationTemplateTag[jj\ o_\ y_]

[DoubleLongRightArrow]NotationTemplateTag[y_[o_]]] may not have been 

entered using the palette, or the embedded TemplateBox may have been 

deleted. The embedded TemplateBox ensures correct parsing and 

retention of proper styling and grouping information"*

The actual problem:

The notation choice I took was:

```
Notation[NotationTemplateTag[o_ /@\ y_  ] \[DoubleLongRightArrow] NotationTemplateTag[Map[y_,o_]]];Notation[NotationTemplateTag[o_ @@\ y_  ] \[DoubleLongRightArrow] NotationTemplateTag[Apply[y_,o_]]];Notation[NotationTemplateTag[o_ @\ y_  ] \[DoubleLongRightArrow] NotationTemplateTag[y_@o_]];
```

This notation choice adds the extra difficulty that the composite notation /@\ is considered to be a syntax error according to Mathematica but it does work if I use the notation package in a notebook.

the error I get when using @\ instead of jj :

Syntax::sntx:
Invalid syntax in or before
"Notation[NotationTemplateTag[o_ @\ y_  ]              "
[DoubleLongRightArrow] NotationTemplateTag[y_@o_]]
^

#### What I tried:

failed attempt #1:

```
BeginPackage["notations`",{"Notation`"}]

(..notations)

EndPackage[]
```

failed attempt #2:

```
BeginPackage["notations`",{"Notation`"}]

/@\::usage="postfix map"

Begin["`Private`"]

notations

End[]

EndPackage[]
```

failed attempt #3:

```
BeginPackage["notations`",{"Notation`"}]

Notation::usage="notation"

Begin["`Private`"]

notations

End[]

EndPackage[]
```

failed attempt #4:

```
BeginPackage["notations`"]

<< Notation`

notations

EndPackage[]
```

maybe some other combinations of those.

---

#### Seperate questions:

- Is there a way to stop mathematica from highligting custom notation choices like /@\ in purple as if they were syntax errors ?
- I think there is a way for mathematica to define custom notations at startup but I forgot how.

Comment: in the line ```BeginPackage["notations`",{"Notation'"}]``` do you see the difference between the last characters of the two strings? The first one is correct, the second is not

Comment: @JasonB. thank you. I fixed that and checked again and I still can not figure out how to add notations to a package.  I will give a simpler example first.

Comment: Are you trying to define a notation using the Notation package and then use that notation *within* your package code?  Or do you want to define a notation within your package that can be used by users of your package in a notebook?  Based on [this comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/250209/how-to-run-a-mathematica-package-m-which-depends-on-notation-package-via-p#comment627177_250209) I don't know if the first one is possible.

Comment: @JasonB. I would like the first option. When I load the package with << notations` in a notebook I receive the errors above.