# Mathematica style plotting in Python?

Tags: plotting, python

This question has two related parts. I recently started using more python because it is easier to setup remote machines (and cheaper). But I really miss Mathematica's plotting capabilities and syntax.

First question, is there a way of using Mathematica for plotting numpy data from jupyter notebook?

Second question, has anyone tried replicating Mathematica's plotting engine or syntax in Python or any other language?

Comment: [Related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4643/how-to-use-mathematica-functions-in-python-programs)

Comment: Altair's concept of [declarative visualization](https://altair-viz.github.io/) seems to be close in spirit with Mathematica's paradigm. As opposed to, say, [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/), which does not only use a different syntax but also a different paradigm.