# How to connect Wolfram Engine to Jupyter on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, jupyter-notebook

I followed the instructions at https://github.com/WolframResearch/WolframLanguageForJupyter/blob/master/README.md

```
wolframscript configure-jupyter.wls add
```

but I get

```
configure-jupyter.wls: Provided Wolfram Engine binary path does not exist.
```

so I tried

```
wolframscript configure-jupyter.wls add ["/usr/local/Wolfram/WolframEngine/12.0/SystemFiles/Kernel/Binaries/Linux-x86-64/WolframKernel"]
```

where the path shown is the result of starting wolframscript and doing

```
First[$ComamndLine]
```

and get the same result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It has been reported that the official Jupyter client from Wolfram works fine on Windows and Mac at the moment. However, some have gotten it to work under Linux by supplying the right path argument to the kernel [as in this GitHub ticket](https://github.com/WolframResearch/WolframLanguageForJupyter/issues/28). See [cc-wr's comment below](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/199063/27662).

An alternative iPython/Jupyter notebook "kernel" called [JWLS](https://github.com/Ludwiggle/JWLS) should work out of the box

There is an actively developed iPython/Jupyter notebook kernel called [iWolfram](https://github.com/mmatera/iwolfram) that *should* work with the Wolfram Engine, but there seems to be a few wrinkles to iron out. [This GitHub ticket](https://github.com/mmatera/iwolfram/issues/11) tracks progress on iWolfram support for Wolfram Engine.

In the mean time, you can still call Mathematica from Python code as you always have been able to do: [How to use Mathematica functions in Python programs?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4643/how-to-use-mathematica-functions-in-python-programs).

This answer is a community wiki which should be updated by anyone as more details are available.

Comment: "only works on Windows" It works fine on Mac (didn't try Windows).

Answer (score 4):

> I followed the instructions at https://github.com/WolframResearch/WolframLanguageForJupyter/blob/master/README.md
>
> ```
> wolframscript configure-jupyter.wls add
> ```
>
> but I get
>
> ```
> configure-jupyter.wls: Provided Wolfram Engine binary path does not exist.
> ```

This issue should be fixed with the most recent commit.

> so I tried
>
> ```
> wolframscript configure-jupyter.wls add ["/usr/local/Wolfram/WolframEngine/12.0/SystemFiles/Kernel/Binaries/Linux-x86-64/WolframKernel"]
> ```
>
> where the path shown is the result of starting wolframscript and doing
>
> ```
> First[$ComamndLine]
> ```
>
> and get the same result.

You do not need the square brackets.

Also, you may run into an issue with your use of the ".../SystemFiles/Kernel/Binaries/..." `WolframKernel` path: it may not be meant to be called directly by the user.

Instead, you should use the "canonical" `WolframKernel` path in `Executables`. An example is below:

> /usr/local/Wolfram/WolframEngine/12.0/Executables/WolframKernel

Comment: No difference. I'll try uninstalling jupyter & the engine and then reinstalling everything later.

Comment: The most recent commit should make the script no longer produce the "Provided Wolfram Engine binary path does not exist." error on Linux immediately.

Comment: With it, I can no longer reproduce these issues with the install method.

Comment: I am sorry that you are having such difficulty with the project. If you have any interest in helping us out, please feel free to create an issue for whatever problems you continue to have here:

Comment: https://github.com/WolframResearch/WolframLanguageForJupyter/issues

Comment: Ok, latest commit & reinstalling anaconda and then editing my .bashrc got it all working. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for something that just works give a try to https://github.com/Ludwiggle/JWLS
If your wolframscript works, JWLS works too, cause JWLS is a bash kernel that reads and writes to fifos; as such, it hardly fails.